# Flask app shows only 1 image and does not show other images

Tags: python, flask, electron

I have flask application via python. In my page, there is three images but flask only shows one of them.

I could not figure out where is the problem.

Here is my code.

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<img style="width:40%;padding:5px" src="static/tomato.png"/>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-warning"><a style="color:white;" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect">Tomato Analysis</a></button>
</div>
 
<div class="col-xs-4">
<img style="width:40%;padding:5px" src="static/grapes.png"/>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-warning"><a style="color:white;" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect">Grape Analysis</a></button>
</div>
```

## PYTHON

```
@app.route("/main")
def index():
    return render_template('gui2.html')
```

It shows tomato.png but it did not sohws the grapes.png, what is the problem of it and how can I solve it.

Also I am using electron.js. After running python script, I am running nmp start.

## The error is output is:

`GET /%7B%7B%20url_for('static',%20filename%20=%20'image/corn2.png')%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the route main to mainPage. Try below code

```
@app.route("/mainPage")
def index():
    return render_template('gui2.html')
```

Comment: Why ? what is the purpose of it ?

Comment: That shouldn't affect the result ideally.

Comment: Once time ı had a problem similar to this, when I changed it, it worked. I am really not sure but it may be /main  could be reserved

Comment: Thanks anyway, I  will try.

Comment: It is worked but I made it lost of changes and I am not sure whether it is the case or not.

Answer (score 0):

The error message 404 clear tells that the resource you are looking for was not found in the given location. Make sure that the file exists on the path you give. Simply, as tomato.png file is displayed correctly, just make sure that other files are also in the same location as tomato.png

Try opening in Incognito or private browser.

Comment: I checked it, it is next to tomato.png image

Comment: That is strange because I ran my code an it worked. make sure images are in static folder. Also, try opening in incognito